# Meaning of "toyed and pondered"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found the expression "toyed and pondered" in the text below. I tried to translate this expression and I also researched what its meaning could be but I couldn't find anything that made me understand it.

Link: https://www.termpaperwarehouse.com/essay-on/Matrix/286678

> ...In the film The Matrix, the question being asked is whether or not anything in this world that we experience every day, from the trees that are growing outside, to the people we encounter on a daily basis, truly exists. In The Matrix film, this question is answered with a resounding “No,” that nothing is real and that the true nature around us is a harsh and cruel reality, one where the entirety of the Earth’s population is enslaved to a race of “machines.”
>
> The main character, Neo, is at first scared about everything he is now experiencing, questioning whether or not if he’s actually dreaming. However, he does come to terms with the fact that he is in fact living in the real world, and his new mission in life is to save as many people as possible from the lies of the machines. The Wachowski siblings, the two people who created the trilogy weren’t the first people to experiment with the concept of a “real” world outside of our “fake” reality.
>
> Philosophers dating back to the time of Rene Descartes, and even further back to the age of Plato, have **toyed and pondered** with this concept. Even though their concepts are all generally the same, the way they perceive it is very different. For example, the Greek philosopher Plato had this concept of a man who was trapped in a cavern his entire life and was physically restrained with tethers, so that he could not move. The only thing available to him was a fire that would cast shadows on the walls and he would only know these shadows......

Comment: It’s not particularly idiomatic. To *ponder* is to think about, mull over, consider, ruminate on. To *toy with*, in contexts like this, is to play with, to experiment with, to “try on for size.”   One doesn’t “ponder **with**.”

Comment: What @PaulTanenbaum said. So don't get too attached to this rather peculiar combination of verbs, because you might *never* encounter another context where juxtaposing them would make sense! :)

Comment: ...though I will say that ***toying*** with something is usually "aimless", whereas ***tinkering*** with something usually has a purpose - often, trying to make something *work* (better). And obviously ***pondering*** is usually purposeful (trying to make sense of "reality", here). So I'm not surprised that Google Books has a couple of instances of [tinkered and pondered](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tinkered+and+pondered%22), but none at all of [toyed and pondered.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22toyed+and+pondered%22)

Comment: **Toyed with and pondered** would make more sense, as @PaulTanenbaum says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an expression. It's the separate verbs "toy" and "ponder", both with the *theme* "this concept".

Further, the grammar is wrong because the verb "toy" takes a "with"-phrase complement, while "pondered" takes a direct object. You can "toy with a concept", and you can "ponder a concept", but you cannot "ponder with a concept".

Here's one grammatically correct re-writing:

> Philosophers ... have toyed with and pondered this concept.

BTW, sites like TermPaper Warehouse are not reliable sources of good writing. This particular essay is awful.

Comment: This is an example of a sentence that is still poorly written even when revised to be grammatical.